# Find duplicate of array of Bitarray

Tags: c#

I have array of Bitarray (each element consists of 128 bits) and I want to find the duplication of each element of it.
I've tried this code:

```
  for (int i = 0; i < final.Length; i++)
            {
                final[i] = BitArrayToStr(sub_string[i]);

            }  
       var duplicates = final
      .GroupBy(s => s)
      .Where(g => g.Count() > 1)
      .Select(g => g.Key);
      var dict = new Dictionary<string,int>();
      foreach (var num in final)
      {
          if (!dict.ContainsKey(num))
          {
              dict.Add(num, 0);
          }
          dict[num]++;
      }
      bool dup=false;
      foreach (var kvp in dict)
      {
          if (kvp.Value != 1)
          {
              Console.WriteLine("{0} repeats {1} times", kvp.Key, kvp.Value);
              dup = true;

          }
      }
      if (dup == false)

      { Console.WriteLine("NO DUPLICATE"); }

      Console.WriteLine("END");


        static String BitArrayToStr(BitArray ba) //**** **** convert bit 
        array to string of chars **** 
    {
        byte[] strArr = new byte[ba.Length / 8];

        System.Text.ASCIIEncoding encoding = new System.Text.ASCIIEncoding();

        for (int i = 0; i < ba.Length / 8; i++)
        {
            for (int index = i * 8, m = 1; index < i * 8 + 8; index++, m *= 2)
            {
                strArr[i] += ba.Get(index) ? (byte)m : (byte)0;
            }
        }

        return encoding.GetString(strArr);
    }
```

but I don't want to convert it to string because the results will be false.
I want to know the duplication of each element of array of bitarray.
Can anyone help?

Comment: Your goal is not clear to me. Do you want to know if more then two bits are 0 or 1? Because that would hit half of them and makes little sense. Do you want to know if any two 128 Bit patterns have the exact same pattern? I would propably end up using some variation of bubble sort for this. It has the interesting property that every single element will be compared to every other element, but only exactly once. Other sorting might skip elements for efficiency. The whole conversion to string makes no sense.

Comment: `Do you want to know if any two 128 Bit patterns have the exact same pattern?`  Yes exactly, what do you mean about `The whole conversion to string makes no sense`??

Comment: bubble sort will only sort the bitarray, I need to find the duplication (I cant follow 10,000 elements or more by myself to find the duplication)

Comment: The question still isn't clear to me - are you looking for a straight "Every element is unique" or "There's at least one duplicate", or are you trying to find *which* elements are duplicates? I also don't understand what you mean by "but I don't want to convert it to string because the results will be false". It would really help if you could post a [mcve] with expected output and actual output, paying attention to formatting it as readably as possible.

Comment: `or are you trying to find which elements are duplicates?` yes , also I need to know how many times it dublicated

Comment: I would expect your `GroupBy` to give you that information very simply - just find which groups have a count of more than 1, and the count will tell you how many times that value occurs. But again, a [mcve] (with careful formatting for clarity) would make it *much* easier to help you.

Comment: If you got a class that represnets a BitArray/BitPattern, write a Compare Method for that class. First converting the BitPattern to string to then to a string comparision is just plain useless overhead.

Comment: I also said to adopt the BubbleSort, not actually sort. One important rule for finding Duplicates is that you want to compare each element against each other element - but **only** once. And as luck would have it, BubbleSort just has that property. Just instead of a More/Less comparision you do a Equal Comparision. And instead of a swap, you mark off a Duplication case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's pretty easy to convert a BitArray to a string of 1s and 0s:

```
static public string ToBitString(this BitArray This)
{
    return string.Join("", This.Cast<bool>().Select( bit => bit ? 1 : 0 ));
}
```

With this knowledge, we can write an EqualityComparer for BitArray, like this:

```
public class BitArrayComparer : IEqualityComparer<BitArray> 
{
    public bool Equals(BitArray a, BitArray b)
    {
        return a.ToBitString() == b.ToBitString();
    }

    public int GetHashCode(BitArray o)
    {
        return o.ToBitString().GetHashCode();
    }
}
```

If we pass the EqualityComparer to `GroupBy` we can now get our counts very easily:

```
var list = new List<BitArray>
{
    new BitArray(new bool[] { true,  true  } ),
    new BitArray(new bool[] { true,  false } ),
    new BitArray(new bool[] { true,  false } ),
    new BitArray(new bool[] { false, false } )
};

var groups = list.GroupBy( item => item, new BitArrayComparer() );

foreach (var g in groups)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Value '{0}' occurs {1} times", g.Key.ToBitString(), g.Count());
}
```

Output:

```
Value '11' occurs 1 times
Value '10' occurs 2 times
Value '00' occurs 1 times
```

Link to [example code on DotNetFiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/GOwkj7)

Comment: How can I convert 'var list = new List<BitArray>
{
    new BitArray(new bool[] { true,  true  } ),
    new BitArray(new bool[] { true,  false } ),
    new BitArray(new bool[] { true,  false } ),
    new BitArray(new bool[] { false, false } )
};' and put my array of bitarray instead of these elements

Comment: You don't. To use your own list, just replace `var groups = list.GroupBy( etc )` with `var groups = myList.GroupBy( etc )`. I think in your case it is `var groups = final.GroupBy( etc )`.

Comment: `Extension method must be defined in a non-generic static class` this error occurred

Comment: It's an extension method. Check [the sample code](https://dotnetfiddle.net/GOwkj7) to see how it works.

Comment: I remove the keyword `this` from this line `static public string ToBitString(this BitArray This)` and it works.